# Jquery show/hide is not working on my server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to show the text field if yes and hide it if we select no radio button.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
                    if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
                        $("#OrderNumber").show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#OrderNumber").hide(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Yes:<input type="radio" name="Order" value="yes" id="order_yes"/>
        No:<input type="radio" name="Order" value="no" id="order_no" checked="checked"  /><br><br>

        <input style="display:none;" name="OrderNumber" id="OrderNumber" size="5" /><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

i had tried the same code online and it was working fine but on my server the text field is not showing up. Anyone who could help me out with this.

Comment: post your site name will check it.

Comment: FYI - your if/else block can be replaced with `$('#OrderNumber').toggle(this.value == 'yes');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the googleapi jQuery `script` and your own jQuery code in separate `script` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
                $("#OrderNumber").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#OrderNumber").hide(); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the jQuery script in it's own script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    Your script here
</script>
```

Works fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aws6/)

Comment: OP may wish to add `type="text"` to definition of `<input id="OrderNumber" etc >` element

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending your code with in the `<script type='text/javascript'>`

So make sure it is placed between script tag like...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
             $("#OrderNumber").show();
          }
          else {
             $("#OrderNumber").hide(); 
          }
       });
   });
</script>
```